# timer as decorator in a class using self.logger to log

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, logging, decorator

I have a class with a bunch of functions and I just implemented logging similar to the code below. Now I would like to time some functions and log the time they took to run. The example below works but I am not very satisfied with the implementation. Is there a better way? I am running this in python 3.6.9.

```
import logging
from time import time, sleep

class Cls(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print('Class initialized')
        self.name = name
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler('Log_'+self.name+'.log')
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    def timer(function):
        """
        times a function and logs the time it needed to run.
        """
        def wraper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            start = time()
            result = function(self, *args,**kwargs)
            end = time()
            self.logger.info(f'The function {function.__name__} ran in {end-start} seconds.')
            return result
        return wraper
   @timer 
   def func(self):
        sleep(1)
```

Edit: The timer function does now not take self in as its first argument but a function. So it should be a staticmethod? But it can't be as the wraper function takes in self as an argument.
Furthermore the timed functions need to take in self as the first argument else it does not work. I would prefer a more general solution with a wraper that takes in any (*args, **kwargs) such that I can time any function in my class.

Comment: what is dis-satisfying you about this implementation? a "better way" often depends on the context and the goal. it is not easy to give a pertinent answer with so few detail. additionally answers could be opinion-based. I am not sure this question is relevant in this form.

Comment: @Tryph Ok I tried specifying what a 'better way' would look like to me.

Comment: ***any (*args, **kwargs) such that I can time any function***: What makes you think this is not possible, See [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/HugeRotatingInterfacestandard#main.py)

Comment: indeed the `timer` method should be a `staticmethod`